# INET error during startup OMNeT++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I build the INET project and everything goes fine.
When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Starting...

$ cd /home/user/Desktop/omnetpp-5.0/temp/inet/tutorials/wireless
$ opp_run -r 0 -n ../../examples:../../src:.. -l ../../src/INET --debug on-errors=false omnetpp.ini

<!> Warning: opp_run: Cannot check library ../../src/INET:../../src//libINET.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3osg5Group11removeChildEPNS_4NodeE


<!> Error during startup: Cannot load library '../../src//libINET.so': ../../src//libINET.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3osg5Group11removeChildEPNS_4NodeE.
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2016 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.0, build: 160414-aa4629c, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

End.
```

INET is a fresh installation in a new workspace (/temp). I have another workspace where it works fine without any problem. There is also a third workspace where it was working fine and then suddenly after clicking on "clean project" for a different project that is using INET, it doesn't work anymore and it gives the same error as the one reported here.

I don't understand where is the problem coming from.

Comment: Which INET version are you using?

Comment: INET 3.4, I don't know what happened but it was working fine and then I clicked on clean instead of build and this error appeared. I cannot find a solution, maybe now I also messed with openscengraph. I installed it but I don't think I had to

Comment: Did you make sure that the Visualization feature is enabled? If it is disabled, then older INET versions like 3.4 have problems since the visualization dependency wasn't (yet) correctly included in all other features before INET 3.5.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with visualisation feature?

Comment: Go into the INET project settings (right-click on the INET project -> properties), check under OMNeT++ -> Project Features that the "Visualization" feature is enabled before you build your INET project.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. There is no OMNeT++ section in the properties menu of INET project, how is that possible?

Comment: How did you import the INET project? Might be the case, that it got imported as a regular C/C++ project instead of an OMNeT++ project?
Do you see the OMNeT section in the properties menu of the OMNeT samples?

Comment: but it was there when I first imported the INET. How is that possible?

Comment: No clue. You could try to delete the project from your workspace (not deleting the files on the disk though) and then afterwards import the project as an "existing project" once again and see if the OMNeT features are there afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> `<!> Warning: opp_run: Cannot check library ../../src/INET:../../src//libINET.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3osg5Group11removeChildEPNS_4NodeE`

means that there is a problem with the function named "NodeE..." in the file "Group11removeChildEPNS". Maybe the function was declared in th .h but not implemented in the .cc.